# Error in REML code of running Linear Regression Model Equation

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to run this code:

> lm_height<-lmer(Height_cm_JUN~ENTRY+(1|REP), data=ASM_HEIGHT18_CL, REML=FALSE)

But I get this error:

> Error in mkRespMod(fr, REML = REMLpass) : response must be numeric

I don't understand what part of my data is not "numeric" here is the head summary of it:

> $ PLOT         : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>
> $ ROW          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>
> $ RANGE        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>
> $ REP          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
>
> $ ENTRY        : int  989 965 931 936 983 926 969 883 911 897 ...

....

> $ Height_cm_JUN: Factor w/ 30 levels "","55","56","58",..: 13 21 17 20 27 17 20 22 15 12 ...

Can someone give me advice on what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.
I appreciate it ---many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is the variable `Height_cm_JUN` which has to be `numeric` (as indicated by the error message), but is a `factor` variable instead. You can turn them into a numeric value by using `as.numeric` combined with `as.character` (since you have want the labels of your `factor`):

```
ASM_HEIGHT18_CL$Height_cm_JUN <- as.numeric(as.character(ASM_HEIGHT18_CL$Height_cm_JUN))
```

Comment: Thanks that helps hopefully the rest of the code will work.

Comment: I have a follow up question with the code : lm_height<-lmer(Height_cm_JUN~ENTRY+(1|REP), data=ASM_HEIGHT18_CL, REML=FALSE).... R should recognize that Height_cm_... is numeric now correct? If it still give the REML error then what?